# I live in a quadruple, yet prefer to be a twin - who am I?

Tags: riddle

> I live in a quadruple,
>   Yet prefer to be a twin.
>   All I can do is move up and down,
>   and left and right.
>   You can make me jump,
>   but only once.
>   I will watch my sides,
>   If you will watch my corners right.

**Who am I?**

Comment: Has a correct answer (now) been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Piecing together the clues you may be a

> Rook

I live in a quadruple, Yet prefer to be a twin

> There are 4 rooks in a chess set, but pieces only like their own side so a rook prefers to be a twin. Thanks @Zizy Archer for the explanation.
>
>  Original opening was - a rook lives in a square chess board, starts as one of two pieces, and the chess player is usually stronger with two rooks.

All I can do is move up and down, and left and right.

> Rooks move vertically or horizontally.

You can make me jump, but only once.

> Rooks can perform the special move castling at most once where it 'jumps' over the king.

I will watch my sides, If you will watch my corners right.

> Rooks can attack and so are defended up/down and across their four sides, but are defenceless to diagonal corner attacks.

Comment: Quadruple likely refers to 4 at the start, but you like just 2 of those (yours).

Comment: @ZizyArcher : There are 4 Rooks , each player has 2 with them, that is preferred.

Comment: Would this not make you a castle? Since you can watch you can move up and down and left and right, "Not up and down while moving left and right in equal scales".

Comment: @PStag: A rook *is* a castle; "rook" is just the more common name.

Comment: @Tom you got the answer right, but the explanation of quadruple isn't correct. SSJGSS and Zizy Archer got it right.

Comment: @SSJGSS (tagged) just so you can see.

Comment: @ZizyArcher (tagged) just so you can see.

Comment: Thanks @ZizyArcher and SSJGSS for finding the opening explanation. Also to prog_SAHIL for this!

Answer (score 1):

You may be

> A Joystick Gamepad

Are You?

Comment: Can you please add in some explanation of why this matches the riddle? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please explain why you believe this is the answer? Answers without explanation are generally deleted.

Comment: Nope. + @Prashant how can you make a joystick gamepad jump?

Comment: I don't know if throwing it through the TV counts as jumping, but that is generally a one time only thing...

Comment: @Foon not necessarily... it'll be a one-time thing for your TV, but some controllers are durable enough that you can plug them back in and keep using them (and throw them into your new TV too!)

Answer (score 1):

it is

> the moon!

live in a quadruple

> 4 weeks

prefer to be a twin

> Dark side and bright side

up and down

> of course, it travel the sky by rising and by setting

left and right

> depending if you are looking the moon from south hemisphere of earth or right hemisphere you will see it going from left to right or from right to left

You can make me jump but only once.

> well if you are able to make the moon jump, bad things would happen, earthquakes on earth, etc. the moon will be probably crush in fragments and take thousand years to become again a heavenly body.

I will watch my sides,
If you will watch my corners right.

> moon is always drawed with eyes looking the dark side, you have to see it in your mind since dark side cannot bee seen on night, but depending on moon phase, it will look both sides, left and right.